# File download problem in WildFly 18.0.0 - response headers missing

Tags: wildfly-10, wildfly-15, wildfly-18

I have updated my WildFly server from 10.1 to 18.0.0.

Now I'm facing wired issue while download PDF as well as XLSX or any file  larger than 15kb.

Say for example,

if I try to download XLSX file of size 100kb,

I find some headers (like - Content-Type, Content-Length, Content-Disposition, etc.) missing from response object although I set those explicitily from my application while writing file in response output stream. As a result the file is getting downloaded of uknown format.

But if I try to download XLSX file of size less than 16kb, the file is getting downloaded in correct format will all response headers present as I set.

I know it's too wired and parhaps this question seems silly or owakward but let me assure you that everything was good until we had older WildFly 10.1.

Can anyone give an idea what could be the reason?

Thanks
Jeet

Comment: Do you get errors? Could you post the log, please? And could you post your method too? Are you using JSF, JSP...?

Comment: I get No error. Neither in server log nor in browser console. I use struts2/spring architecture and my frontend is written in JSP. I use jQuery `$.fileDownload`from front-end to initiate download & my controller writes file content in response output stream